# RealmObject AND Parcelable

Tags: java, android, realm, parcelable

Using Realm for Android I have a class:

```
public class Entry extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    ...
}
```

`Parcelable` interface contains methods like `describeContents()`, `writeToParcel()` and RealmObjects aren't supposed to have methods other than getters and setters:

> Error:(81, 17) error: Only getters and setters should be defined in model classes

How can I make these two work together? Is there a better way than creating an separate class (maybe something like `RealmEntry`)? Doing so would result in a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Parcelable objects and Realm?

Comment: Well, I use Pareclable to preserve objects upon configuration changes (device rotations), and Realm to store objects onto a db

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just requery the database after a configuration change? This might even be faster, considering you are using RealmDB which comes with caching mechanisms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now there's a different workaround for that: just implement the `RealmModel` interface instead of extending from `RealmObject`:

```
@RealmClass
public class User implements RealmModel {

}
```

You can find more information in the [Realm Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/java/latest/io/realm/RealmModel.html).

Comment: But is it a good idea to use parcelable objects to store data?

Comment: refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896751/android-store-a-parcelable-object-in-sqlite

Comment: The link doesn't work and this solution doesn't seem to do anything, why is it marked as the answer? I changed my 'RealmObject' to a 'RealmModel' and it still complains that it's not parcelable.

Comment: The link is now updated. Regarding doing "anything", instead of extending an object and inheriting all Realm methods, you will now have to use  RealmObject static methods, like `/* With the RealmModel interface */  RealmObject.isValid(p);` instead of `/* With the RealmObject base class */  p.isValid();`. Refer to the updated documentation for more information.

Comment: @behelit instead of immediately voting down an answer, a bit more search effort on your part could be made, don't you agree?

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE May 2016:** This is answer is now out-dated unless you already use Parceler. @Henrique de Sousa's solution is much better.

---

Actually, there is a workaround. You can get the result you want if you're willing to use a third-party library (Parceler) for `Parcelable` generation. See [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689104/504611), quoted below for convenience.

> With [Parceler v0.2.16](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/57#issuecomment-70130449), you can do this:
>
> ```java
> @RealmClass      // required if using JDK 1.6 (unrelated to Parceler issue)
> @Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = { Feed.class })
> public class Feed extends RealmObject {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Then, use `Parcels.wrap(Feed.class, feed)` instead of `Parcels.wrap(feed)` everywhere, otherwise your app will crash with `org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to create ParcelableFactory for io.realm.FeedRealmProxy`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at the moment to implement Parcelable on RealmObjects.
One solution is to Use two realm files: the default one as your object store and a specialized one for temporary saves for rotations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Kotlin:

```
import io.realm.com_labtest_di_model_EntryRealmProxy
import org.parceler.Parcel


@RealmClass
@Parcel(implementations = arrayOf(com_labtest_di_model_EntryRealmProxy::class),
    value = org.parceler.Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
    analyze = arrayOf(Movie::class))
open class Entry() : RealmObject() {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Parceler does not work in android x.
You can use this:

```
class ExParcelable @JvmOverloads constructor(data: Any? = null) : Parcelable {
    var cls: String? = null
    var json: String? = null

    init {
        if (data is Parcel) {
            cls = data.readString()
            json = data.readString()
        } else {
            cls = data?.let { it::class.java }?.canonicalName
            json = Gson().toJson(data)
        }
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(cls)
        parcel.writeString(json)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    fun value(): Any? {
        return Gson().fromJson(this.json, Class.forName(this.cls))
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Creator<ExParcelable> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ExParcelable {
            return ExParcelable(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ExParcelable?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

and :

```
inline fun <reified T : Any?> Intent.extra(key: String): T? {
    var value = extras?.get(key)
    if (value is ExParcelable) {
        value = value.value()
    } else if (T::class == Uri::class) {
        if (value is String) {
            value = value.toUri()
        }
    } else if (T::class == String::class) {
        if (value is Uri) {
            value = value.toString()
        }
    }
    return value as T?
}

inline fun <reified T : Any?> Intent.extra(key: String, value: T?) {
    when (value) {
        null -> {
            // no op
        }
        is Uri -> putExtra(key, value.toString())
        is Boolean -> putExtra(key, value)
        is BooleanArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Byte -> putExtra(key, value)
        is ByteArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Char -> putExtra(key, value)
        is CharArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Short -> putExtra(key, value)
        is ShortArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Int -> putExtra(key, value)
        is IntArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Long -> putExtra(key, value)
        is LongArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Float -> putExtra(key, value)
        is FloatArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Double -> putExtra(key, value)
        is DoubleArray -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Date -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Bundle -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Parcelable -> putExtra(key, value)
        is Serializable -> putExtra(key, value)
        is RealmObject -> putExtra(key, ExParcelable(value.get()))
        else -> putExtra(key, ExParcelable(value))
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
new Intent().apply{
    extra("test", realmObject)
}
```

and :

```
intent.extra("test")
```