# Usage of parceler (@Parcel) with Realm.io (Android)

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable, realm, parceler

I have the following code which produces the error: `Error:Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type io.realm.Realm for io.realm.RealmObject.realm`

It was working all fine without `extends RealmObject` , however I want to use Realm to put to database easily. Is there a way to exlcude the RealmObject fields and just use the basic pojo fields for @Parcel?

```
@Parcel
public class Feed extends RealmObject{
    int id;
    public String text;
    public String time_created;
    String time_modified;
    int comments_count;
    int likes_count;
    String feed_type;
    int obj_id;
    String image;
    String user_name;
    String user_earthmile_points;
    boolean liked;
    boolean commented;
    boolean is_private;
    String url;
    int feed_creator_id;

   }
```

Comment: See https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/57

Comment: Technically, I have never seen a use-case in which it makes sense to parcel a RealmObject. You're supposed to only send primary keys.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT #2**: Actually, I found a way to make it work :). See the updated answer below.

**EDIT #1**: While the app compiles just fine, it crashes when trying to actually create a `Parcel` with the error: `org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to create ParcelableFactory for io.realm.FeedRealmProxy`. The Realm team has [officially acknowledged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27268065/504611) that it is currently not possible to implement `Parcelable` on `RealmObject`s. It is unclear if / when this will be resolved.

---

With [Parceler v0.2.16](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/57#issuecomment-70130449), you can do this:

```java
@RealmClass      // required if using JDK 1.6 (unrelated to Parceler issue)
@Parcel(value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = { Feed.class })
public class Feed extends RealmObject {
    // ...
}
```

Then, use `Parcels.wrap(Feed.class, feed)` instead of `Parcels.wrap(feed)` everywhere, otherwise your app will crash with `org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to create ParcelableFactory for io.realm.FeedRealmProxy`.

Comment: Will it use Serialization? I've heard serialization is 10x slower than parcel. I don't want to compromise on performance. So should I use this technique or use some other work around?

Comment: @penduDev No. Parceler will still create standard Android `Parcel`s, you don't need to worry about that. That's its whole job :) (To be very clear actually, even creating a `Parcel` is a form of "serialization", so it is not correct to say "serialization is 10x slower than parcel". Instead you should say, "using the Java `Serializable` interface is slower than creating a `Parcel`", and the reason for *that* is, [`Serializable` creates lots of temporary objects which causes a lot of GC](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)).

Answer (score 1):

All classes that extend RealmObject will have a matching RealmProxy class created by the annotation processor. Parceler must be made aware of this class. Note that the class is not available until the project has been compiled at least once.

```
@Parcel(implementations = { PersonRealmProxy.class },
    value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
    analyze = { Person.class })
public class Person extends RealmObject {
// ...}
```