# Saving AwarenessFence into database

Tags: android, google-awareness

In my Android app I use Fence API from Awareness Fence, and all works as expected.

However, I need to reset the fence when the device reboots. For this purpose I have built a BroadcastReceiver on device boot.
My problem is: how can I save the AwarenessFence object into the database?

Thank you.

Comment: `AwarenessFence extends Object implements Parcelable`, so you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896751/android-store-a-parcelable-object-in-sqlite